# Quick way to iterate through two arrays python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

I've had multiple scenarios, where i had to find a huge array's items in another huge array.
I usually solved it like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(arr1)):
        for k in range(0,len(arr1)):
            print(arr1[i],arr2[k])
```

Which works fine, but its kinda slow.
Can someone help me, how to make the iteration faster?

Comment: For starters start iterating *Python*icly: instead of `for index in range(len(array)):`, use `for element in array:`

Comment: In the inner loop, do you mean `arr2`?

Comment: When you say "find a huge array's items in another huge array", what do you mean? that's not just iterating. Can you give an example with inputs and outputs?

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like you want to use sets/dicts for fast O(1) lookup

Comment: @Chris_Rands it means that i need to iterate trough two array with 200 items each. Which means im printing out 200*200 lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = [4,5,6,7]
same_items = set(arr1).intersection(arr2)
print(same_items)
Out[5]: {4,5}
```

Sets hashes items so instead of O(n) look up time for any element it has O(1). Items inside need to be hashable for this to work. And if they are not, I highly suggest you find a way to make them hashable.

Comment: `set(arr1).intersection(arr2)` will work

Comment: Thank you, i went with your. solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle huge arrays, you may want to use Python's `numpy` library, which assists you with high-efficiency manipulation methods and avoids you to use loops at all in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

if your array has duplicates and you want to keep them all:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,7,5,4]
arr2 = [4,5,6,7]

res = [i for i in arr1 if i in arr2]
>>> res
'''
[4, 5, 7, 5, 4]
```

or using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.array(arr1)[np.isin(arr1, arr2)].tolist()
>>> res
'''
[4, 5, 7, 5, 4]
```